# Private key or password for Account that is deployed on remix

Tags: private-key

I have deployed new contract on remix ethereum got Contract Adress as well as account address
but now i want private key or password for my account address
how to get that because while creating i have connected with JAVAScript VM for some reason web3 inject is not working on my laptop so now i confuse what to do and how to get Private key for my account address which i have created and when i am connecting Injected web3 it is connecting to Metamask but at below it says Currently you have no contract instances to interact with.
I am not understanding what to do ..?? please help..!!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript VM is a temporary blockchain instance in browser memory. If you reload the browser or the remix page then it will restart discarding previously deployed contracts.

Injected Web3 uses the web3 provider available in the browser, usually a wallet like Metamask.

The contracts deployed on Javascript VM are separated from the ones accessible by Injected Web3.

Javascript VM is used for quick testing, something you can discard. For more complex and longer interactions with contracts you want to use Injected Web3 and connect Metamask to a testnet like Rinkeby, or your own private testnet.